# Free alternative to angular ide

Tags: gratis, open-source, angularjs, eclipse

Is there a free alternative (not necessarily open source) to [angular ide](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular-ide) as eclipse plugin that supports angular 5. We're currently using [angular eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular-eclipse) but it's buggy.

Comment: Are you definitely tied to Eclipse? Lots of folks are using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for their Angular development, including Angular 5.

Comment: @JohnY told the senior that but he'd like to stick to eclipse since the backend is java, maven, spring. If VS integrates as well with those as eclipse, I might convince him to switch. Angular is just the front end

Comment: I'm a little late to the party here, but I like http://brackets.io/ It does realtime update of the Angualr page in the browser as I update my code files.

Comment: @Mawg Does it support angular 1.x?

Comment: Yes, it does. I can't tell you about later Angulars, becuase I am too lazy to elarn TypeScript. I was very happy with Brackets; give it a try & post back here - no matter whether you like it or not, an opinion will help others

Comment: @Mawg Post an answer and I will accept it in order to close the question. It doesn't matter if I like it or not, it's the only option out there right now, which make you answer, not only a valid  answer, it means that your answer is the only valid answer to this question

Comment: Now that I re-read your question, I ma not sure that it *_is_* an answer. Your question can be read two ways. Are you looking for an Eclipse plug-in? If so, Brackets won't help, as it is a standalone IDE & I have misunderstood your question. To be honest, I would be happy with an Eclipse plugin, since I also use Eclipse for C/C++ and PHP.

Comment: Of course, nowadays, the accepted free answer would be Visiual Studio code, which is very, veyr good. Hower, I am more than happy to pay `first year £45.00 second year £36 third year onwards £27.00` for the incomparable WebStorm. It simply can't be beat.